# populating DOM based on user input - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm new to ruby and rails so please forgive me if its really simple. I've been trying to manipulate DOM based on a dropdown selection. The code follows:

```
<%= form_for :sale, url: sales_path do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :buyer_details %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :buyer_details %>
</p>
<p>
  <% transaction_collection = ["Cash", "Credit"]%>
  <%= f.label :nature %><br>
  <%= f.select :nature, transaction_collection%>
</p>
<% if @nature == "Credit" %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :debtor_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :debtor_id, @debtors, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

In a way I want to hide/show the debtor based on the nature dropdown selection. As of now, it is never displayed.

I understand that this can be done with the help of java/coffee script. But I would like to do it with erb (if it's possible).

Comment: somebody down-voted the question, care to give feedback?

Comment: If you want to manipulate DOM without page reload then js is only sane option. And its pretty easy to do so its not surprising you got downvoted

Comment: @MartinZinovsky thanks for the inputs. I already said that in the question that I know it can be done in js. Can it be done in erb file? If yes, how? is the question. I still don't see a point to down-vote.